# Filter dataframe with two regexes

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this dataset:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'col_a' : [np.nan, 'in millions', 'millions', 'in thousands', 'thousands', np.nan, 'thousands', 'abcdef'],
                      'col_b' : ['2009', '2009', '2009', '2009', '2009', '2009', 'abc', '2009'],
                      'col_c' : ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', 'def', '2010'],
                      'col_d' : [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'thousands', np.nan, np.nan]})
```

Producing:

```
          col_a col_b col_c      col_d
0           NaN  2009  2010        NaN
1   in millions  2009  2010        NaN
2      millions  2009  2010        NaN
3  in thousands  2009  2010        NaN
4     thousands  2009  2010        NaN
5           NaN  2009  2010  thousands
6     thousands   abc   def        NaN
7        abcdef  2009  2010        NaN
```

I want to filter that dataframe for each row that

1. has four digits (and potentially whitespace before or after the four digits); I use the regex `\s*?\d{4}\s*?` for this.
2. has either 'millions' or 'thousands' in any column (`millions|thousands`) or is NaN, but not strings other than 'millions' or 'thousands'.

That is, I want rows 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I do this:

```
mask = frame.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'\s*?\d{4}\s*?',
                                                        regex = True,
                                                        flags = re.IGNORECASE,
                                                        na = False)).any(axis = 1)
test = frame[mask]
mask = test.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'(in)?millions|thousands',
                                                       regex = True,
                                                       flags = re.IGNORECASE,
                                                       na = False)).any(axis = 1)
test = test[mask]
test
```

Which gives:

```
          col_a col_b col_c      col_d
1   in millions  2009  2010        NaN
2      millions  2009  2010        NaN
3  in thousands  2009  2010        NaN
4     thousands  2009  2010        NaN
5           NaN  2009  2010  thousands
```

Row 0 misses in the filtered dataframe as it has NaN in col_a and col_d. And, Python throws a warning:

> UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
>
> #  Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.

How can I change this to also include row 0? If I changed the second regex to `(in)?millions|thousands|NaN`, I also get rows 6 and 7, which is not what I want.

**EDIT**: In this dataset, I know that col_a and col_d contain NaN for row 0. In the real dataset, I do not know in which column the NaNs appear. That is, more generally, the filtering conditions are:

1. one column of a row has to contain four digits (the first regex), and
2. any other column may contain a string but that string can only be 'millions' or 'thousands'

Comment: You're almost there, First make the first mask `mask1` and the second `mask2`, then I think you want: `df = frame[mask1 & (mask2 | frame['col_a'].isna())]` then `print(df)`.Ps, well done on writing a well structured question!

Comment: Thanks Erfan. That works for this specific dataset. But in the real dataset that I use, I do not know in which column the NaN appears. Do you have an idea about that as well? That is: one column of a row has to contain four digits (the first regex), and any other column may contain a string but that string can only be 'millions' or 'thousands'. I have updated the original question for this.

Comment: But following your logic row 7 contains 4 digits and NaN, so should be included. So your logic is: "the colum with `millions` or `thousands` should not contain any other string" correct?

Comment: Row 7 contains 4 digits but the string 'abcdef', so that should not be included. And the logic should be: a row may contain a column with a string, but that string can only be `millions` or `thousands`.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody has a similar problem: I found negative lookaheads to work for me:

```
mask = frame.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'^(?!.*?thousand|.*?million|\d{4}).*?$',
                                            regex = True,
                                            flags = re.IGNORECASE)).any(axis = 1)
test = frame[~mask]
test
```

Produces:

```
          col_a col_b col_c      col_d
0           NaN  2009  2010        NaN
1   in millions  2009  2010        NaN
2      millions  2009  2010        NaN
3  in thousands  2009  2010        NaN
4     thousands  2009  2010        NaN
5           NaN  2009  2010  thousands
```